# Resharper and ViEmu Keybindings ( and Visual Assist )

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-assist, viemu

With ViEmu you really need to unbind a lot of resharpers keybindings to make it work well.

Does anyone have what they think is a good set of keybindings that work well for resharper when using ViEmu?

What I'm doing at the moment using the Visual Studio bindings from Resharper. Toasting all the conflicting ones with ViEmu, and then just driving the rest through the menu modifiers   (  Alt-R  keyboard shortcut for the menu item ).    I also do the same with Visual Assist shortcuts  ( for C++ )

if anyones got any tips and tricks for ViEmu / Resharper or Visual Assist working together well I'd most apprciate it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also create mappings in ViEmu that will call the VS and R# actions.  For example, I have these lines in my _viemurc file for commenting and uncommenting a selection:

```
map <C-S-c> gS:vsc Edit.CommentSelection<CR>
map <C-A-c> gS:vsc Edit.UncommentSelection<CR>
```

The :vsc is for "visual studio command," and then you enter the exact text of the command, as it appears in the commands list when you go to Tool>Options>Keyboard

I don't use any of the R# ones in this way, but it does work, as with:

```
map <C-S-A-f> gS:vsc ReSharper.FindUsages<CR>
```

Comment: I knew about the _viemurc/.viemurc file, but I didn't realize you could map commands to VS ones with vsc. Very good tip!

Answer (score 2):

I use both as well, but I'm using the IntelliJ keybindings instead, so I can't speak specifically to the Visual Studio bindings. [J.P. Boodhoo has some changes that he has made via AutoHotKey](http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2008/07/vs-viemu-resharper-modded-with-autohotkey) to provide additional Vim-like functionality to Visual Studio + ReSharper + ViEmu.

I have removed a few of the scanned keys, though, because I want to keep some of the ReSharper functionality over the ViEmu functionality, though the way I use these tools change over time as I learn more shortcuts from either ViEmu or ReSharper.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed the following, which may be useful to know.  **Some of the ReSharper keyboard mappings that ViEmu hoses, will work once you have a different ReSharper dialog open.**  *I use the IntelliJ IDEA-based shortcuts, but I assume this will work similarly for ReSharper's VS scheme*.

**Example:**  ViEmu binds to `Ctrl+N` which R# uses for `Go To Type`.  However, ViEmu does not bind to `Ctrl+Shift+N` which R# uses for `Go To File`.  Therefore, if you hit `Ctrl+Shift+N` **the Go To dialog is launched**.  You can then take your finger off Shift and hit N again and **the dialog will switch** to `Go To Type`.

This is very useful, if like me you use `Go To Type` a lot and don't really want to mess with the keyboard mappings.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jay noted the best way is to set up custom bindings.

Here is example of bindings at https://github.com/StanislawSwierc/Profile. I created my bindings based on the previous at https://github.com/w1ld/viemu_settings

Answer (score 0):

I use both plugins, but I really prefer the power of the Vi input model that ViEmu gives. I really don't miss so much the Resharper keybindings...