# Prevent ReSharper from interfering with ViEmu's Enter handling in doc comments?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, viemu

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with ViEmu 2.5, and recently added ReSharper 7.1, which causes a problem: When I'm in normal mode and press Enter, it's now creating a new line within the comment (whereas in vi normal mode, Enter should just *move* to the first non-blank on the next line, not insert one). It's driving me a bit batty.

*(Update: Ooh, it also interferes if I'm in a doc comment and type `:` to start typing an ex command; I can type the command but I can't press Enter to excute it!)*

It's definitely ReSharper that's causing this to happen (either directly, or by somehow making the keystroke bypass ViEmu and go to VS's default handling), as it only started when I installed ReSharper, suspending ReSharper makes it stop, and resuming ReSharper makes it start again.

Interestingly, this doesn't happen *outside* documentation comments. Enter in vi normal mode outside doc comments works normally.

I've kicked around the settings and a couple of questions here (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87381/resharper-and-viemu-keybindings-and-visual-assist)), but haven't yet found a way to get those keystrokes back to ViEmu. I've told ReSharper not to set any of its keyboard shortcuts at all (**ReSharper Keyboard Scheme: None**), and in its options I've turned off all of the XML Doc Comments stuff I can find (even things I'm actually going to want, like word-wrapping). But no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to upgrade to ViEmu 3, which in addition to several other new features, offers better interoperability with ReSharper. There was no setting to change, just uninstalling 2.5 and installing 3.0 did the trick. (I then did the obvious experiment to rule out installation order: I uninstalled 3.0 and reinstalled 2.5. That made the problem reappear.)